# Flash Video Variables into Facebook OpenGraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

How the heck to people do this? Grooveshark does it, Youtube does it. How do they get flash variables into the swf via the querystring?

Here's a link to my OG code and I know it's fine:

https://recordmob.com/s/yc

You can see in my source that the og:video property is set properly:

But how the heck do I get that id into Flash in the news feed on facebook without access to ExternalInterface of any other variable tools in OG?

I'm pulling my hair out here!!! AAAAAAAAAAA.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I removed the ExternalInterface call which was disallowed by Facebook for security reasons and stumbled upon loaderInfo.loaderURL to get the querystring id. I then just do a remote call to pull in everything via a json encoded string. Works like a charm.

My strategy with stack overflow is to ask a question 8 hours after working on something. 10 minutes after asking, I find the answer online. SO is my Saint Anthony, Patron of Lost Things.